# error in moving std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++

I try to run this code to move the unique_ptr's from the first vector to another, in the copy constructor:

```
class Text
{
    struct paragraph
    {
        int index;
        string text;
    };

    vector<unique_ptr<paragraph>> paragraphs; 

public:

    Text()
    {
        paragraphs.push_back(unique_ptr<paragraph>(new paragraph));
    }

    Text(const Text & t)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < (int)t.paragraphs.size(); i++)
        {
            paragraphs.push_back(move(t.paragraphs[i]));
        }
    }
};
```

and i got this error:

```
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory(208): error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Text::paragraph
1>          ]
// Etc.
```

Comment: **unique** _ptr. `vector::push_back` makes a copy. But `unique_ptr` has no public copy ctor.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Not necessarily, there's an overload of `push_back` that takes an rvalue reference.

Comment: Why does your copy constructor move? I'm pretty sure you can't move const references. You should do that in the move constructor `Text(Text&&)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code.

First, you cannot move from a `const&`, and this applies to members of a `const&` too. Movement is destructive; you should only move from a `&&`. Your copy constructor should *copy*; if you don't want a copy constructor, then `= delete` it or whatever your compiler allows.

Second, assuming you took a `Test &&` for a proper move constructor, you should not move each element like that. Instead, move the vector into the new one like this:

```
Text(Text && t) : paragraphs(std::move(t.paragraphs)) {}
```

Third, you should only write this function assuming that your compiler of choice doesn't support automatically generated move constructors (ie: is Visual Studio). If it does support it, you *shouldn't write one at all*. Let the compiler do it's job.

Answer (score 0):

```
Text(const Text & t)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)t.paragraphs.size(); i++)
    {
        paragraphs.push_back(move(t.paragraphs[i]));
    }
}
```

In this constructor `t` is const, so `t.paragraphs[i]` gives a const lvalue reference to a `unique_ptr`.

`move(t.paragraphs[i])` turns that into a const *rvalue* reference, but it's still const.  The `unique_ptr` move constructor needs a non-const rvalue reference, so isn't viable, so the deleted copy constructor is the best match.  you shouldn't be trying to move the contents of `t` in a copy constructor, that's what move constructors are for.

You should also say `std::move` not just `move`, to prevent ADL finding the wrong move.